Can we get a better example question for our site tour?
I just happened to visit our tour page, and noticed that the example answers shown there are... not quite the kind we'd really like to encourage:



Part of the problem is that the tour page requires the example questions and answers to be fairly short, and to avoid certain Markdown features like code blocks.  Apparently, the actual top answer to the current example question doesn't qualify, so what gets shown are the two runner-ups, both of which are link-only answers.
So, here's a challenge: Can we find a better question that actually qualifies for the tour page, and has at least one actually good answer that also qualifies?

Update: Apparently, we only have two questions that qualify: the current one and this other one.  Given our limited options, I wonder if switching between them would actually be an improvement.
Or perhaps we could try to deliberately make a better example question...

I switched it to the other question, as I think it is a lot better for the tour. We could definitely try to deliberately make a better one.

Thanks! Looking at the tour page now, I agree -- the new question and its answers look a lot better.

I forked the query and extended the body length to 550 instead of 400. That could give us some options where selective editing of the question and some of the answers could get us an even better question for the tour.

BTW, since I asked this question, we've gained a few more questions that qualify for the tour page. In particular, this one or this one could both be decent choices. I kind of like the current one for its simplicity, though; the other two are considerably more advanced questions.
